# max7219 chained display showing mirrored text

Tags: arduino-uno, c, max7219

I'm using a max7219 like this one max7219. When I first tested my circuit, I used an 8x8 display and the code worked just fine. Now, after I modified the code with the one that can be found online at [arduino code](https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_Parola) and changed the display with the chained one, the text appears to be mirrored on the matrix display.

[image: like in this picture].

Below, I'll attach part of the code. Please help me find the problem.

```
#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Define the number of devices we have in the chain and the hardware interface

#define MAX_DEVICES 4
#define CLK_PIN     13
#define DATA_PIN    11
#define CS_PIN      10

// Hardware SPI connection
MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
// Arbitrary output pins
// MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

void setup(void)
{
  P.begin();
  P.displayText("Hello", PA_CENTER, 0, 0, PA_PRINT, PA_NO_EFFECT);
}

void loop(void)
{
  P.displayAnimate();
}
```

Comment: Changing the incorrect line to **#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW**
did the trick. It took time to find, but thanks a million!!!

Comment: In my case I had to change to **#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::ICSTATION_HW**

Answer (score 6):

Since version 3.0 `MD_MAX72xx.h` no longer supports that definition. Now the hardware type is defined as a parameter on creation (in the "Example" file you are using - not in `MD_MAX72xx.h`)

```
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
...
MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
```

Note that I've changed the hardware type from `PAROLA_HW` to `FC_16`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the configuration in MD_MAX72xx.h file and ensure you have the right module selected.

For example there is a define

```
#define USE_PAROLA_HW   0
```

if your hardware is this item then turn off the other hardware settings and turn this one on so it reads as follows:

```
#define USE_PAROLA_HW   1
```

there many other settings if it is not there then you will have to experiment until you find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In library, change `#define USE_GENERIC_HW 0`  to `#define USE_GENERIC_HW 1` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of `#include <MD_Parola.h>`, `#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>` you have to define the following and characters will display correctly.

```
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
```

Comment: Isn't that what @Den1al said in their answer?